# How to create a new SQL Database on different drive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have installed SSMS 2014 recently on my new machine, installations are in C: but my C: is not having that much enough space, so I need to create the new database on D:. Please help me on how can I do that ?

Comment: uninstall an re-install on D: ??

Comment: Have you tried anything? The "New Database" dialog box shows the path for the new database in the very first page.

Comment: Just modify your create database script to point to D: drive. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Comment: Or, click on the "Generate Script" button of the "New Database" dialog, to have SSMS generate the script for you

Comment: use the appropriate value for *`filespec`* when you call `CREATE DATABASE` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Comment: you can set the path of .mdf, and .ldf file while creating the new databse

Comment: This is a valid and helpful question. I'm not sure why you guys vote it down!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can set the path of .mdf, and .ldf file while creating the new databse. See the Red Arrow pointer. You can choose here your D drive path.

Steps:- Open SQL Server Management Studio >> Right Click on Database >> Choose New Database >> Then below dialog box will be shown.

[image]